# PowerShell: How To Use Methods and Arguments

Tags: oop, shell, powershell, command-line

## About Methods' Syntax:

I heard about two syntaxes of parameter declaraton. I use the first one for `MulT` and the other one for `MulV`:

```
$MathObject = (New-Module {
    function MulT([int]$Factor1, [int]$Factor2) {
        $Factor1 * $Factor2
    }

    function MulV{
        param(
            [int]$Factor1,
            [int]$Factor2
        )
        return $a * $b
    }
} -AsCustomObject)
```

What's the difference between the syntax of `MulT` and the syntax of `MulV`? Which should I use?

## Named Arguments:

Cmdlets can have named arguments:

```
Multiply-IntegerFactors -Factor1 5 -Factor2 8
```

Can methods of objects have named arguments too? I'm thinking about something like:

```
$MathObject.MulT(-Factor1 5, -Factor2 8)
```

***EDIT:*** Do you think that it's a good solution to use a **hash table as argument** in order to store the named arguments there?: `$MathObject.MulT(@{Faktor1=5, Faktor2=8})` - Or is there any better solution?

## Conventions On Methods:

There are strict naming conventions on Cmdlets (`Verb-CamelCaseNoun`) and modules (`CamelCaseModuleName`). Are there any (naming) conventions on methods too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in how the parameters are declared will make no differences in these 2 functions.  In general, you have more flexibility to modify parameters using attributes if you use the param() syntax.  There does seem to be an issue with the names of the parameters and how they are referenced in the body of the MulV function ($factor1/2 and $a/$b).

As far as using named parameters for methods, that doesn't work.

Comment: `> There does seem to be an issue with the names`: Sorry for the bad example code, but thankfully I just created it as demo for my question and never used it in any serious project.

Comment: Is there something you know about naming conventions on methods too?

Comment: Another thing: Do you think its a good solution of the named argument problem to use hash tables as argument?: `$MathObject.MulT(@{Faktor1=5, Faktor2=8})`

Comment: I would think that the method and module naming conventions would be similar.  There's definitely an issue with using dashes in method names.  I actually blogged about issues around this [here](http://powershellstation.com/2012/02/08/importing-modules-using-ascustomobject/).  Using hashes would give you some more flexibility in passing parameters using names, but the syntax gtets a bit nasty.

Comment: No, it does not.  You could even use "write-output $a*$b"